# Automatic routes discovery Camel

Tags: java, xml, spring, apache-camel

In my application I have some xml files stored in a folder which declare my routes. I'd like to upload all my routes at the application bootstrap and store them in my camel context. In other words, I want to auto-discover routes stored in those xml files.

Here is an example of the files containing routes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<routeContext id="myRoute" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="file:C:/LocalFTPServer" />
        <log message="Got a file!" loggingLevel="INFO" loggerRef="myLogger" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${file:ext} == 'csv'</simple>
                <log message="I'm going to email you!" loggingLevel="INFO"
                    loggerRef="myLogger" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <log message="File extension wrong." loggingLevel="WARN"
                    loggerRef="myLogger" />
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </route>
</routeContext>
```

and here is my application context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <import resource="beans/beans.xml" />

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

Comment: What about `<import resource="classpath*:/routes/*.xml"/>`?

Comment: in that way you import the files, but you don't "register" the routes contained in them in the camel context. I'm looking for something to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add routes on some event just use `context.addRouteDefinitions` method

For example:

```
    public class ContextStartEventListener extends EventNotifierSupport implements ApplicationContextAware {

        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }

        @Override
        public void notify(EventObject event) throws Exception {
            if (event instanceof CamelContextStartedEvent) {
                try {
                    CamelContextStartedEvent startedEvent = (CamelContextStartedEvent) event;
                    DefaultCamelContext context=(DefaultCamelContext)startedEvent.getContext();
                    Resource[] xmlResources=applicationContext.getResources("classpath*:net/**/route.xml");
                    for (int i=0;i<xmlResources.length;i++) {
                        InputStream is = xmlResources[i].getInputStream();
                        RoutesDefinition routes = context.loadRoutesDefinition(is);
                        context.addRouteDefinitions(routes.getRoutes());
                    }       
                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    // do something on error
                }
            }
        }
...
```